# How to implement any lib in build.gradel in Android studio Chipmunk?

Tags: android, android-studio, implementation, chipmunk

Doesn't implement any of external lib in Android studio Chipmunk

Answer (score 0):

You can follow either of these steps -

```
dependencies {
// Dependency on a local library module
implementation(project(":mylibrary"))

// Dependency on local binaries
implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))

// Dependency on a remote binary
implementation("com.example.android:app-magic:12.3")}
```